# Understanding two sums leetcode problem (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

I am working on the [Leetcode Two Sums](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) problem: "Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.". This is what I have:

```
def two_sum(nums, target)
  hash = {}
  nums.each_with_index do |num, index|
    diff = target - num
    if hash[diff]
      return [hash[diff],index]
    else
      hash[num] = index
    end
  end
end
```

The code works, however, I'm not too sure why this works.

So I understand that in the each statement it goes through the numbers and it finds the difference. For example,

```
nums = [4,2,5,1]
target = 6
```

On the first loop, the difference is 6-2 = 4. But the hash is obviously empty so it will register num as a key, with the current index as the value. Thus the hash is,

```
hash = {
  4: 0
}
```

On the second loop, the difference is 6-4 = 2. hash[4] is nil so it will add the current num and index to the dictionary.

```
hash = {
  4: 0
  2: 1
}
```

Like so, wouldn't this keep adding the nums to the hash, because at least in this case there aren't matching key value pairs?

Maybe I am overcomplicating things. If someone could eli5, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: This returns `nums` if no pair of numbers sum to `target`, so you might add `nil` as the penultimate line. You might also replace the `if/else/end` construct with `return [hash[diff], index] if hash.key?(diff); hash[num] = index`.

Comment: Short-and-sweet, though not as efficient: `nums.each_index.to_a.combination(2).find { |i,j| nums[i]+nums[j] == target }`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is that we add the value to the hash using the *number* as the key:

```
hash[num] = index
```

but extract it using the *diff* as the key:

```
if hash[diff]
```

So if you have as input:

```
nums = [4,2,5,1]
target = 6
```

Then on first step, the difference is 6 - 4 = 2, there's no key 2 (diff) in the map, and we add the key 4 (number) to the map.
On the second step, the difference is 6 - 2 = 4, and there's already a key 4 (diff) in the map, so we return the value.

Comment: Oh my god this makes so much sense! 
I feel dumb lol. Thank you guys for clearing it out!